# How to expand collectionview cell to full screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm trying to print the image on fullscreen
I used UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
here my code is

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let itemWidth = collectionView.bounds.width
        let itemHeight = collectionView.bounds.height
        return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)
    }
```

but it doesn't show the content on full screen it makes space from top and bottom

Comment: try it make page enabled

Comment: I want to expand cell to full screen, as far as I know page enabled will provide me navigation via layout. But I want to expand uicollectionview cell to full screen

Comment: Every cell or specific cell?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to increase cell size to fit to your screen you can use this method.

## Objective-C

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
}
```

## Swift

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        //For entire screen size
        let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
        return screenSize
        //If you want to fit the size with the size of ViewController use bellow
        let viewControllerSize = self.view.frame.size
        return viewControllerSize

        // Even you can set the cell to uicollectionview size
        let cvRect = collectionView.frame
        return CGSize(width: cvRect.width, height: cvRect.height)


    }
```

Comment: I'm able to do that now. Is it rational or is it right way to present a view in collectionview cell? Is there a better way to do this.

Comment: Be sure to also set collection view's Estimate Size to None in the storyboard, otherwise the size won't change even though the above sizeForItemAt method is being called.