# How to set constraints on a UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uistoryboard, nslayoutconstraint

I want my cell's width to be the same as the screen's width on every screen size. I can't set constraints in the storyboard since the option is greyed out, and setting them programmatically results in an error that says something like "Unable to activate constraint with anchors...because they have no common ancestor" even though I'm only setting the constraints to be the view's leading and trailing anchors.

The way the storyboard is setup now, the cell is at the desired width on iphone SE and that same width on the larger screen sizes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to expand collectionview cell to full screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40346165/how-to-expand-collectionview-cell-to-full-screen)

Answer (score 3):

you can use delegate method

```
viewcontroller:UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize.init(
            width: collectionView.bounds.height,
            height: collectionView.bounds.height
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you to set the `collectionView` width same as the screen width.
In your `viewDidLoad()` write this code

```
let height: CGFloat = 100.0 //Some constant
let width: CGFloat = self.view.frame.width

let spLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
spLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
```